# Does this Trigonometry question even make sense?

Tags: trigonometry

**Line *f* is drawn from the origin and $(-5,8)$. The angle formed by this line and the x-axis is $\theta$. What is $\cos \theta$?**

I want the answer to be $-5/\sqrt{89}$ , so would I need to specify the angle is being formed by the positive x axis (forming some angle of about $120$, and therefore giving a negative cosine value)?

If I specified the negative x-axis instead, would I still get a negative cosine value, or would it be positive due to the relative frame giving an angle of something around $60$ degrees (despite the fact that the actual x component of the line is still negative)?

Is this even a math issue at this point or just a problem with math semantics?

Thanks!!

Comment: Any line not vertical or horizontal makes two distinct supplementary angles with the x axis, so to me the wording of your problem is ambiguous.

Comment: right, I figured it was. So if I was indeed determined to make the answer to this question $−5/\sqrt89$ what would i have to do to accomplish that

Comment: The vector $(1,0)$ points in the direction of the positive x-axis. If you knew the direction vector of your line you could use dot product to get the desired angle. However another problem arises, as your line has two distinct direction vectors, one pointing in either direction along the line.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! <> Did the question arise in connection with _polar coordinates_ by chance? If so, that matters; if not, please carry on....

Comment: Thanks Andrew! No in fact I came up with this question all on my own to try and convey the concept that cosine will sometimes result in negative values specifically because the side length adjacent theta is negative.

Comment: @yaboi6969: Welcome to Math.SE! ... *"I came up with this question all on my own"* Please add this context to the body of the question. (Comments are easily overlooked and may be hidden.) As is, the question reads (to me) like you're trying to interpret and/or fix something you've taken from a textbook. So, I believe you could be clearer that you're looking for advice on how best to phrase an exercise that you've created. You might give the intention of the exercise, its intended audience, your current phrasing, and then what you see as potential issues. And add the `article-writing` tag.

Comment: @yaboi6969: As to the style issues ... If this question is being asked in total isolation, then you need to fill in some technical gaps. As has been mentioned, a line makes multiple angles with "the x-axis". Even if you specify "the positive x-axis", there's an orientation ambiguity: do you mean the *counterclockwise* obtuse angle, or the *clockwise* acute one? Alternatively, talk about the *ray* from the origin through the given point. ... If this is one of numerous exercises, have a preamble that establishes whatever conventions you want to use, to allow exercises to be more concise.

Comment: If you consider the angle with the negative x-axis, you are against the international and only way to define the angle of  line **f**. The hidden answer given by @bjcolby 15 below was correct.

Comment: @Piquito I'm sorry I can't seem to find bjcolby15's answer, it seems it's a bit too hidden for me. I see they made an edit, but nothing more. Could you relay it to me?

Comment: @yaboi6969 It was the now hidden second answer to your problem (I can see it, with a downvote, in my page of MES). Regards.

Answer (score 1):

> If I specified the negative $x$-axis instead, would I still get a negative cosine value, or would it be positive due to the relative frame giving an angle of something around $60$ degrees (despite the fact that the actual $x$ component of the line is still negative)?

You would get a positive cosine value in that case.

When you learn the trigonometric functions for angles of any size (including obtuse angles) using the unit circle definitions, the cosine of an angle is simply the $x$ coordinate of the point where one side of the angle crosses the unit circle. In that context, the cosine and the $x$ coordinate must have the same sign.

But those definitions assume that the angle's vertex is at the origin **and** that the angle is measured from the positive $x$ axis. If you are measuring some other angle in the plane, those assumptions are not always true. Therefore neither is the conclusion about the sign of $x$.

Without clues from the other subject matter of the textbook, it's hard to be sure what they mean in this question. They might have a practice of writing "angle with the $x$-axis" when they really mean "angle with the positive $x$-axis" (this was the interpretation that came to my mind while reading the question), or they might mean the smaller angle formed by the two lines, which would be the angle between the negative $x$-axis and the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(-5,8)$ (as you astutely point out in the question). I cannot be sure.